# Удалить/запретить пробелы вначале инпута

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Нужно удалять пробелы вначале input, но с этим справляется регулярка

```
$(document).on('input', '[type="text"]', function () {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^\s/,''));
});
```

А если в input вставить строку с множеством пробелов вначале строки, то удалится только первый, а остальные останутся.
И нужно чтобы не затирало полностью input, а удаляло только пробелы вначале строки.
Пробел в середине текста разрешен.
Помогите плиз.....

Comment: добавьте плюс `/^\s+/`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Добавьте плюс `/^\s+/`

Спасибо splash58

Comment: Что мешает использовать .trimLeft()? Он полностью удаляет все начальные пробелы.

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов описан здесь: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimStart

и здесь:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_string_trim_start.asp

str.trimStart() или str.trimLeft(). Но есть свои ньюансы (описаны в документации)